Scraping data from Twitter without Twitter API
I am currently working on my master thesis. I want to run an sentiment analysis on the tweets directed at airlines that are about their sustainability initiatives. I wanted to use the API of X but Elon Musk thought it was necessary to ask for $100 per month to acces the data. Some guys from MIT found a way around this paywall.

https://medium.com/@vladkens/how-to-still-scrape-millions-of-tweets-in-2023-using-twscrape-97f5d3881434
https://github.com/vladkens/twscrape/tree/main

But the thing is that I am not familiar with the use if Python. Normally I use R for all my data analyzes, so I don't know what I have to do. I need a CSV file with the tweet and the date so that I can run my analysis in R again.
I think I've altered the code so that I only get the tweets and the date but I can't seem to get the output. The code stops after logging into the account that I've made for this to work. Before I actually got some output but I wasn't able to export it to a CSV file unfortunately.

import asyncio
from twscrape import API, gather
from twscrape.logger import set_log_level

async def main():
    api = API()  # or API("path-to.db") - default is `accounts.db`

    # ADD ACCOUNTS (for CLI usage see BELOW)
    await api.pool.add_account("pevers123", "2051Lb57", "peter.evers123@hotmail.com", "2051Lb57")
    await api.pool.add_account("maxevers123", "2051Lb57", "max.evers123@hotmail.com", "2051Lb57")
    await api.pool.login_all()


    # API USAGE

    # search (latest tab)
    await gather(api.search("easyjet eco-friendly environment", limit=20))  # list[Tweet]
    # change search tab (product), can be: Top, Latest (default), Media
    await gather(api.search("easyjet eco-friendly environment", limit=20, kv={"product": "Top"}))


    # NOTE 1: gather is a helper function to receive all data as list, FOR can be used as well:
    async for tweet in api.search("easyjet eco-friendly environment"):
        print(tweet.user.username, tweet.rawContent, tweet.date)  # tweet is `Tweet` object


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


That guy does not seem to be from MIT. And I would definitely not call it a "way around". You just hoard tons of accounts, that's all.
